# How do I bind an input field in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I've created an input field and I'd like to print the value below it, which mysteriously isn't working. I've been doing this on multiple occasions before so it really is strange. Anyone got any idea what I might be overlooking?

```
<input class="form-control control-search" type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchtext">
<span>{{ searchtext }}</span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full code with js scripts ?

Comment: That'll be hard as it is a massive app! I know it should just be working no matter what the controller looks like?

Comment: As @ashish mentioned, please add more code. In addition, any console errors?

Comment: is searchbox defined?

Comment: I changed it to just be a normal variable rather than an attribute so searchbox isn't needed, but it doesn't make a difference. I basically just joined this project so not sure why this isn't working as with previous project it has always been fine...

Comment: Ok so you got something wrong somewhere... We def can't tell with the 2 lines of code above.. So please share more.

Comment: attribute or not, it should work. No console errors?

Comment: no console errors apart from missing angular maps

Comment: Mine is working fine => https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/14173/. Without any code can't do anything more than that.

Comment: yeh I know it has been working for me in the past, was hoping anyone has run into this before / can share common pitfalls etc as it'll be tricky to share the whole app.

Comment: It is working for me, here is a fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3pz4x6sj/) 
Are you missing something? maybe ng-app??

Comment: Not the whole app, but maybe the controller in which this $scope lives in. Is this a parent controller of another controller perhaps? Anything else that may help, because with the code above its pretty hard to tell.

Comment: Have you used ng-app and ng-controller?

Comment: I have used ng-app and ng-controller

Comment: I'll check whether I can share some other stuff

Comment: Ok so just worked it out - the curly brackets were clashing with handlebars, so they changed them to be like this: {- searchtext -}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in case someone else runs into this in the future:

the devs before me have changed the brackets because they were clashing with handlebars by adding this into the app file:

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{-');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('-}');
```

so I had to change the curly brackets usage to this:

```
{- searchtext -}
```